# Redirect error messages to a file in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7nUb.png)

---

Is it possible to redirect the message in the shell to a file say *error.txt*. I use the following build system

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<input.txt>output.txt2>error.txt"],
    "selector": "source.cpp",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible to redirect the message in the shell to a file "error.txt" using following build system.

```
{
  "cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<input.txt","2>error.txt>output.txt"],
  "selector": "source.cpp",
  "shell": true,
  "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

There must be a space between  input.txt and error.txt so we separate them with a ',' delimeter . 2>error.txt redirects error stream to error.txt file then output stream is redirected to output.txt file.